# Finding the smallest of 3 numbers. (School assignment)

Tags: c++

I am fairly new in programming and I am not quite sure how to do this assignment given to me for school.

> Write a function `void print_min(unsigned char a, short b,int c)`,which prints "Min of (a,b,c)=M". M is the smallest of these 3 numbers. For computing and printing use functions `int min(unsigned char a, short b,int c)` and `printf`.

I tried but I can't seem to be able to make it work as it gives error every time.

This is the code that I tried to use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h> 


void print_min(unsigned char a, short b, int c)
{   
    int m = 0;
    if( a < b ) m = a; else m = b;
    if( c < m ) m = c;
}
int main()
{ 
    unsigned char a; short b;int c;int M;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b; 
    cin >> c;
    M = print_min("a", b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to give me some pointers as to what I need to do. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `M = print_min("a", b,c);` -->  `M = print_min(a, b,c);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your program

**issue 1:**
 print_min is returning void whereas you probably want it to return an int.

```
int print_min(unsigned char a, short b, int c)
{   
    int m = 0;
    if( a < b ) 
        m = a;
    else 
        m = b;
    if( c < m ) 
        m = c;
    return m;
}
```

**issue 2**

```
M = print_min("a", b,c);
```

Function expects an unsigned char, you are sending a string literal `"a"`

```
M = print_min(a, b,c);
```

**issue 3**

You need to explicitly specify `std::` namespace before `cin`

```
int main()
{ 
    unsigned char a; short b;int c;int M;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b; 
    std::cin >> c;
    M = print_min(a, b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

**issue 4:**

```
std::cin >> a;
```

Reads a character, you are sending the ascii value and not the numeric value intended. Better to keep the same type int for all.

```
#include <iostream>

int print_min(int a, int b, int c)
{   
    int m = 0;
    if( a < b ) 
        m = a; 
    else 
        m = b;
    if( c < m ) m = c;
    return m;
}

int main()
{ 
    int a; int b; int c; int M;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b; 
    std::cin >> c;
    M = print_min(a, b, c);
    std::cout << "Smallest of 3 is = " << M << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and 
comprehensive response.